# Installing dependencies in ceph

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ceph

I get a problem when fulfilling dependencies in installing ceph on ubuntu 14.04. Based on the documentation here https://github.com/ceph/ceph/tree/infernalis, the dependencies will be fulfilled by running

```
./install-deps.sh
```

However, on my case, I've gotten an error message like this:

```
uuid-runtime is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libblkid-dev : Depends: libblkid1 (= 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20) but 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.1 is to be installed
                Depends: uuid-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-system-dev : Depends: libboost-system1.54-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-thread-dev : Depends: libboost-thread1.54-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libfuse-dev : Depends: libselinux-dev
 liblttng-ust-dev : Depends: uuid-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libudev-dev : Depends: libudev1 (= 204-5ubuntu20) but 204-5ubuntu20.14 is to be installed
 xfslibs-dev : Depends: uuid-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried to run `apt-get update` and then run `apt-get install -f` 
 But the error still there. In addition, I also tried to install all system upgrade in synaptic but still no luck to solve this problem.

in the last chance, I also try to run `sudo apt-get install libuuid1=2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20`. this command resulting some libs are removed from the system, but the dependencies are still unsatisfied.

Please share me inputs how do I face this problem. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours trying to solve this problem, I found the ubuntu `aptitude` help me a lot here.

The first, I install aptitude by typing:

> sudo apt-get install aptitude

and then install the dependency one by one manually by typing:

> sudo aptitude install DependencyPackage

once I run the command, it will have several options to be chosen. On my case, I ignored the first proposal solution and chose the second one(install some nwq package on my computer).